# 3d times 2d matrices Tensorflow

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow

Suppose I have two tensors of different dimensions.

```
<tf.Tensor 'embedding_lookup:0' shape=(?, 128) dtype=float32>
<tf.Tensor 'Neg:0' shape=(?, 15, 128) dtype=float32>
```

I want to do a matrix multiplication of these two tensors such that I get a final tensor with shape `(?, 15, 1)` or `(?, 15)`. How could I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `X` and `Y` as the `2D` and `3D` inputs respectively, we can use [`tf.einsum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum) -

```
tf.einsum('ij,ikj->ik',X,Y)
```

The output would have a shape of `(?, 15)`.

Comment: Glad to see `einsum`, I saw this morning in numpy. Never knew `tf` had one.

Comment: @Dark Yup, its a new addition into `tf`.